# Where is custom list item information stored in the relationship list in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, variations

In SP2013, relationship list, I want to get information for `custom list items` to get the ID of their variation items. But in the list all I could find is sites, lists and aspx pages. SharePoint does store this information somewhere because for example, if I approve a custom list item, it will create or update if already existing on the target variation list.

Does anyone know about this?